# Identify the ObjectFactory method used to create the object

Tags: reflection, jaxb

Given an object o which was or could have been created with a JAXB ObjectFactory, what's the best way to find the method in that ObjectFactory which would be used to create the object?

My objective is to be able to generate Java code sufficient to recreate that object (ie one or more createXYZ statements).

Does the answer change if I commit to a specific JAXB implementation, say MOXy, for example?

Suppose I just know the object is from some JAXBContext (so one of several ObjectFactory classes could have been used to create it).  Does this change the answer at all?

Where the object is a JAXBElement, @XmlElementDecl comes in to play.  @XmlElementDecl can have a scope. My JAXB objects know their parent, so hopefully this matches scope.

I've written some proof of concept code which uses getGenericReturnType and getAnnotation(XmlElementDecl.class), to find the method, but I'm guessing there is likely to be stuff in one of the JAXB implementations, which could be re-used to do this more effectively/elegantly.